# 3 data frames and 3 rules in operation to insert data into another dataframe - No common columns - Big data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 3 different data-frames which can be generated using the code given below

```
data_file= pd.DataFrame({'person_id':[1,2,3],'gender': ['Male','Female','Not disclosed'],'ethnicity': ['Chinese','Indian','European'],'Marital_status': ['Single','Married','Widowed'],'Smoke_status':['Yes','No','No']})
map_file= pd.DataFrame({'gender': ['1.Male','2. Female','3. Not disclosed'],'ethnicity': ['1.Chinese','2. Indian','3.European'],
              'Marital_status':['1.Single','2. Married','3 Widowed'],'Smoke_status':['1. Yes','2. No',np.nan]})
hash_file = pd.DataFrame({'keys':['gender','ethnicity','Marital_status','Smoke_status','Yes','No','Male','Female','Single','Married','Widowed','Chinese','Indian','European'],'values':[21,22,23,24,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,141,142,0]})
```

And another empty dataframe in which the output should be filled can be generated using the code below

```
columns = ['person_id','obsid','valuenum','valuestring','valueid']
obs = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

What I am trying to achieve is shown in the table where you can see the rules and description of how data is to be filled

[image]

I did try via for loop approach but as soon as I unstack it, I lose the column names and not sure how I can proceed further.

```
a=1
for i in range(len(data_file)):
   df_temp = data_file[i:a]
   a=a+1
   df_temp=df_temp.unstack()
   df_temp = df_temp.to_frame().reset_index()
```

How can I get my output dataframe to be filled like as shown below (ps: I have shown only for person_id = 1 and 4 columns) but in real time, I have more than 25k persons and 400 columns for each person. So any elegant and efficient approach is helpful unlike my for loop.

[image]

Comment: Any other approach to do this is also helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chat and remove duplicates data is possible use:

```
s = hash_file.set_index('VARIABLE')['concept_id']
df1 = map_file.melt().dropna(subset=['value'])
df1[['valueid','valuestring']] = df1.pop('value').str.extract('(\d+)\.(.+)')
df1['valuestring'] = df1['valuestring'].str.strip()

columns = ['studyid','obsid','valuenum','valuestring','valueid']
obs = data_file.melt('studyid', value_name='valuestring').sort_values('studyid')

#merge by 2 columns variable, valuestring
obs = (obs.merge(df1, on=['variable','valuestring'], how='left')
          .rename(columns={'valueid':'valuenum'}))
obs['obsid'] = obs['variable'].map(s)
obs['valueid'] = obs['valuestring'].map(s)

#map by only one column variable
s1 = df1.drop_duplicates('variable').set_index('variable')['valueid']
obs['valuenum_new'] = obs['variable'].map(s1)

obs = obs.reindex(columns + ['valuenum_new'], axis=1)
print (obs)

#compare number of non missing rows
print (len(obs.dropna(subset=['valuenum'])))
print (len(obs.dropna(subset=['valuenum_new'])))
```

Comment: Hello Jezrael, Can you please help me with this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807104/wide-to-long-returns-empty-output-python-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alterternative approach using [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
# Solution for pandas V 0.24.0 +

columns = ['person_id','obsid','valuenum','valuestring','valueid']

# Create map Series
hash_map = hash_file.set_index('keys')['values']
value_map = map_file.stack().str.split('\.\s?', expand=True).set_index(1, append=True).droplevel(0)[0]

# Melt and add mapped columns
obs = data_file.melt(id_vars=['person_id'], value_name='valuestring')
obs['obsid'] = obs.variable.map(hash_map)
obs['valueid'] = obs.valuestring.map(hash_map).astype('Int64')
obs['valuenum'] = obs[['variable', 'valuestring']].apply(tuple, axis=1).map(value_map)

# Reindex and sort for desired output
obs.reindex(columns=columns).sort_values('person_id')
```

[out]

```
    person_id  obsid valuenum    valuestring  valueid
0           1     21        1           Male      127
3           1     22        1        Chinese      141
6           1     23        1         Single      129
9           1     24        1            Yes      125
1           2     21        2         Female      128
4           2     22        2         Indian      142
7           2     23        2        Married      130
10          2     24        2             No      126
2           3     21        3  Not disclosed      NaN
5           3     22        3       European        0
8           3     23        3        Widowed      131
11          3     24        2             No      126
```

Comment: Will update the solution soon.currently away for lunch

Comment: I get an error message like No attribute 'droplevel'. Can you help me understand what's the issue?

Comment: I am just using the same statment (value_map)

Comment: This is a new method added to  `v0.24.0` of pandas.... check your version? `print(pd.__version__)` - maybe just needs an upgrade. You can run `pip install pandas -U` from a terminal if you need to upgrade

Comment: I encountered another error as "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Comment: Mean that there must be duplicates in your data - what is `print(columns) ?`

Comment: Yeah, My dataset is huge so there might be duplicates but it is valid to have such records.

Comment: obs.variable.map(hash_map) - this is the line that causes error

Comment: try running `hash_map[hash_map.duplicated(keep=False)]` to see which values are causing issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194813/discussion-between-avles-and-chris-a).